Model prediction differed after one year with same config and dataset
I tried a TrOCR-Hugging Face model, with a training data (400k) and got around 83% of accuracy with the test data. After a year, I tried to train the same model, with same config and dataset. Now the model predicts only 69% of my test data only.
I used a pretrained model 'microsoft/trocr-base-handwritten' from Hugging Face. And the thing differed was GPU instances. Trained using data_parallel on dual gpus in first attempt (32*2 batch size) and 4 gpus on second attempt (16*4 batch_size).
Is there any other way to reproduce the same results?

try installing library versions from a year ago. See if the results change
